# HTML Canvas lineTo, but with a specific magnitude/length

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a line from the x, y = 0 to the mouse, but I want to set the total length/magnitude of the line so the line doesn't get all the way to the mouse

```
function drawLine(x, y, length) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);

    let hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2);
    
    let newX; let newY; // how do I shorten x & y?

    ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

My question is how could I redo the x and y so the line is in the same direction but not as long?

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to `exampleLength/2`